# understanding complex if condition in modal.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey guys i was just going through the source if modal.js and came across the following line :

```
if (!that.$element.parent().length) {

  }
```

i am new to JS and Jquery in general , what i figure is the not operator is being used here and basicall we are getting the parent element of $element and then accessing the length property . but i still don't quite get the practical usage of this condition .

This condition can be seen on [line 79](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/modal.js#L79) , on git too .

Thank you.

Alex-Z .

Comment: My guess is it's just checking that the given element has been inserted in to the DOM (ie. it has a parent). If you look at the line after, it actually puts it in to the DOM (appends to body) if the check fails.

Comment: if modal not in body get it into body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is basically checking if such an element exists. Every JQuery selector implicitly returns a list of elements, which can be empty. If length is 0, this will evaluate to false in a boolean context, so ! in front will make this condition true if the element does not exist (element list is empty).

Answer (score 1):

It checks if the given element already exists in the the DOM. This logic ensures it will not be added twice:

```
 if (!that.$element.parent().length) {
    that.$element.appendTo(that.$body) // don't move modals dom position
  }
```